# English Characters inside of arabic text arabtex package

Tags: symbols, arabic, embedding

i want to write a paragraph in my French book in arabic, I've used Arabtex package :

```
\begin{arabtext}
بلا بلا english word بلا لا
\end{arabtext}
```

The problem is that I need to show english words inside of arabic paragraph which is not possible in this case, because all the English letters are transcribed to Arabic, and I haven't seen any command in the arabtex manual. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose “english word” inside `\LR{}`, as described in the manual (see the last item in section 2.1 of arabdoc.pdf).  `\LR{}`  is meant for short roman text within an Arabic text.

Better yet, switch to `arabxetex`.